# Issues with ToDo list

Tags: flutter

I have several questions:

How can you create a todo list with deletable tiles, usable checkboxes and how can u save data, that a user put in?
I have currently found a tutorial with stateless tiles where you cant use the tickboxes or delete the tiles...

In my case the whole stuff gets wiped and the toDO list is trash...

Thank you for your help ^^

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: ToDo()));
    
    class ToDo extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ToDoState createState() => _ToDoState();
    }
    
    class _ToDoState extends State<ToDo> {
      List<String> products = ['Tomate', 'Käse', 'Lauch', 'Paprika' ,'Wein'];
    
      void addItem(String item) {
        setState(() {
          products.add(item);
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    
      void newEntry() {
        showDialog<AlertDialog>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: TextField(
                onSubmitted: addItem,
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("To-Do-App"),
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 152, 185, 100),
            ),
            body:
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: products.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return ToDoItem( products[i] );
                },
              ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: newEntry,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
        );
      }

}

class ToDoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const ToDoItem(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        leading: Checkbox(
          value: false,
        ),
        title: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.black54),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```